# How to do Postfix accept outgoing mail from another internal servers

Tags: ssl, postfix, tls, smtp-auth

I have a MTA with Postfix SSL/TLS configured and sending messages perfectly fine. In the same internal network, I have other servers that I want to send mail through this MTA.

In main.cf variable 'mynetworks', I already configured CIDR to accept internal IPs from my network.

Although all this configuration, when I try to send email from another server using this SSL MTA, I have the following error:

```
Jul 29 16:17:04 mail postfix/smtpd[25676]: connect from unknown[192.168.1.128]
Jul 29 16:17:04 mail postfix/smtpd[25676]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from unknown[192.168.1.128]
Jul 29 16:17:04 mail postfix/smtpd[25676]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.1.128]
```

This 'another server' reach my MTA, but I don't know about this error.

I don't know what else to research. All the theoretical knowledge I have was used at all.

Thanks, guys!

========================

## EDIT (30/07/2013)

After enabling debug_peer_list = 192.168.1.128, this was the log output:

```
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: connect from unknown[192.168.1.128]
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 192.168.1.0/24
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: match_hostaddr: 192.168.1.128 ~? 192.168.1.0/24
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: report connect to all milters
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter_macro_lookup: "j"
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter_macro_lookup: result "mail.mydomain.com.br"
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter_macro_lookup: "{daemon_name}"
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter_macro_lookup: result "mail.mydomain.com.br"
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter_macro_lookup: "v"
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter_macro_lookup: result "Postfix 2.6.6"
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_connect: non-protocol events for protocol version 6: 
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_connect: transport=inet endpoint=192.168.1.108:8891
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: trying... [192.168.1.108]
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: vstream_tweak_tcp: TCP_MAXSEG 16384
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_connect: my_version=0x6
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_connect: my_actions=0x1ff SMFIF_ADDHDRS SMFIF_CHGBODY SMFIF_ADDRCPT SMFIF_DELRCPT SMFIF_CHGHDRS SMFIF_QUARANTINE SMFIF_CHGFROM SMFIF_ADDRCPT_PAR SMFIF_SETSYMLIST
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_connect: my_events=0x1fffff SMFIP_NOCONNECT SMFIP_NOHELO SMFIP_NOMAIL SMFIP_NORCPT SMFIP_NOBODY SMFIP_NOHDRS SMFIP_NOEOH SMFIP_NR_HDR SMFIP_NOUNKNOWN SMFIP_NODATA SMFIP_SKIP SMFIP_RCPT_REJ SMFIP_NR_CONN SMFIP_NR_HELO SMFIP_NR_MAIL SMFIP_NR_RCPT SMFIP_NR_DATA SMFIP_NR_UNKN SMFIP_NR_EOH SMFIP_NR_BODY SMFIP_HDR_LEADSPC
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_connect: milter inet:192.168.1.108:8891 version 6
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_connect: events SMFIP_NOHELO SMFIP_NOUNKNOWN SMFIP_NODATA SMFIP_SKIP SMFIP_HDR_LEADSPC
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_connect: requests SMFIF_ADDHDRS SMFIF_CHGHDRS SMFIF_SETSYMLIST
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_conn_event: milter inet:192.168.1.108:8891: connect unknown/192.168.1.128
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: event: SMFIC_CONNECT; macros: j=mail.mydomain.com.br {daemon_name}=mail.mydomain.com.br v=Postfix 2.6.6
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: reply: SMFIR_CONTINUE data 0 bytes
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: > unknown[192.168.1.128]: 220 mail.mydomain.com.br ESMTP Postfix
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: xsasl_cyrus_server_create: SASL service=smtp, realm=mail.mydomain.com.br
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: name_mask: noanonymous
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: watchdog_pat: 0x7f27142f9cb0
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: < unknown[192.168.1.128]: ?g???
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: match_string: ?g??? ~? CONNECT
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: match_string: ?g??? ~? GET
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: match_string: ?g??? ~? POST
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: match_list_match: ?g???: no match
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: report unknown command to all milters
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_unknown_event: milter inet:192.168.1.108:8891: unknown command: ?g???
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: event: SMFIC_UNKNOWN; macros: (none)
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: skipping event SMFIC_UNKNOWN for milter inet:192.168.1.108:8891
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: > unknown[192.168.1.128]: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: watchdog_pat: 0x7f27142f9cb0
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: smtp_get: EOF
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 192.168.1.0/24
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: match_hostaddr: 192.168.1.128 ~? 192.168.1.0/24
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from unknown[192.168.1.128]
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: disconnect event to all milters
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: milter8_disc_event: quit milter inet:192.168.1.108:8891
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.1.128]
```

=======================

## EDIT 31/07/2013

Telnet locally works perfectly fine.

```
[root@mail ~]# telnet mail.mydomain.com.br 465
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to mail.mydomain.com.br.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.mydomain.com.br ESMTP Postfix
ehlo mydomain.com.br
250-mail.mydomain.com.br
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
auth plain AHRlc3R1c2VyADEyMzQ1Ng==
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
```

Comment: try to increase debug level smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1 or even smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2

Comment: One of the problems was solved increasing smtp loglevel, which was ownership of directory /var/lib/postfix. But it keeps with error described above.

Comment: Have you tried to emulate smtp session via telnet? In the log there is no error. Also you could enable debug in the postfix. Just add debug_peer_list = 192.168.1.128

Answer (score 0):

As you can see form the output

```
Jul 30 09:18:13 mail postfix/smtpd[9126]: > unknown[192.168.1.128]: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
```

the client had sent some not recognized command during smtp session. You should check settings on the 192.168.1.128. Also you could save smtp session and analyze them in wireshark/ethereal

```
# tcpdump -w /tmp/smtp_192.168.1.128.log -s 0 -nnpi eth0 host 192.168.1.128 and tcp port 25
```

Comment: I still could not realize why I'm getting this "502 5.2.2 Error: commando not recognized". TCPDUMP does not output anything.

Comment: It saves all data to the file /tmp/smtp_192.168.1.128.log